# Make static out of non-static (Magic Method)

Tags: php, laravel

Hello so basically in Laravel you can do something like this

```
User::get();
```

And I know that behind the scene laravel does this by calling a magic method called `__callStatic()` and returning a `new static` out of it.

**BUT** `__callStatic` only works on inaccessible or non-existing methods.

So my question is that how you can do that `User::get()` when `get()` actually is a `public function`?

**Edit**
Given I have this simple code here

```
class First
{
    public function callThis()
    {
        return 'Yo';
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        dd('This is not working');
    }
}

First::callThis();
```

And I get 

`Non-static method First::callThis() should not be called statically`

Comment: Yes it is public as well as static, `public static`. How do you want to call it ?

Comment: I just want to make a custom class (not a model) with the same functionality but when I call my method it says `Non-static method First::callThis() should not be called statically` I will update my answer to be more specific.

Comment: You might also want to reconsider why you are calling it statically instead of non-statically. If you have control of the class definition, why not make it `public static`? if you don't have control of the class definition, why not call it correctly, eg `$first = new First(); $first->callThis();`?

Comment: I just wanted to dig into the laravel and find out how does it handles models dynamically so we are not forced to make a new object on models everytime...

Comment: Apparently you could also achieve this with `(new First)->callThis();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work because you cannot call non static methods statically.
The reason why it works with methods like `get()` is because these calls are being delegated to the query instance - they don't actually exist on the model itself.

If you check `__call` method, it should all become a bit more clear:

```php
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }

    return $this->newQuery()->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

So even though the default `__callStatic` method implementation calls the non static method on itself:

```php
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

Your code would fail straight away, because your model would actually contain the `public` non-static method with the same name.

You'll see that the `__call` method checks whether the name of the method is within the array of `increment` and `decrement` - and if it is - it calls them.

```php
protected function increment($column, $amount = 1, array $extra = [])
{
    return $this->incrementOrDecrement($column, $amount, $extra, 'increment');
}

protected function decrement($column, $amount = 1, array $extra = [])
{
    return $this->incrementOrDecrement($column, $amount, $extra, 'decrement');
}
```

Both of these methods are actually non-static on the instance of the model, but their visibility is set to `protected` so you wouldn't be able to call them on the instance of the model anyway - the only way to access them is using magic methods - in this case static call will work just fine.

In other words, if you change visibility of your method to `protected` and overwrite the `__call` method to also include your method name in the array, then your code should work

```php
protected function callThis()
{
    return 'Yo';
}

public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement', 'callThis'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }

    return $this->newQuery()->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen `(new static)->$method`. Is this specific syntax allowed in 6.5, or new to PHP 7? Very sexy...

Comment: I can't remember version of PHP that has introduced it, but I've been using it for quite some time.

Comment: is this inline-instantiation allowed outside of the internal method definitions? eg, could the OP achieve what they are wanting by doing `(new First)->callThis();` instead of `First::callThis();`, assuming the goal is to avoid having to instantiate the object (and set to a separate variable) just to call the method?

Comment: Ah, it looks like this is covered in http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-175 "PHP 5.4.0 introduced the possibility to access a member of a newly created object in a single expression". So my suggestion would work, assuming they OP isn't really needing a truly static method so much as a method called from the object in the same expression.

Comment: Of course - you can always wrap the class instantiation and call non-static method on it - it really depends on what syntax you prefer and whether you want to mutate the internals of the framework for a particular model. Personally I kind of like the idea of the static call, but it all depends on your preference.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that if a method can be (and often is) called like in my example (where it is instantiated in the same expression just to call that method) that it's likely that this means the method should be made static (or that the class has a very reliable constructor that often doesn't need further mutation upon instantiation, as in `DateTime`).