# Why I get Non-static method should not be called statically?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel and the way I learn a new framework is going deep and found how/why magic happened in that.
So I learn facades and love them and wanna found how Laravel do the magic and found a way to have similar feature is `__callStatic` magic method. and here is my code :

```
class Facade {
  public static function __callStatic($method,$args){
    $instance = static::getFacade();
    return call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $args);
  }

}


class DB extends Facade {
  public static function getFacade(){
    return new self();
  }

  public function init(){
    echo 'INIT DB';
  }
}


DB::init();
```

the code has a right output but I get this error:

```
Non-static method DB::init() should not be called statically :21
```

I don't understand why I got this and also Why I don't get this error in Laravel application that does this.

Comment: I don’t know if you are familier with Java or not but i am assuming this is a similar situation. In Java if you want to call non-static method, you have to create an object of that class. If you do not want that, you have to make the method static.

Answer (score 1):

As init() is your public method and not static, you can call it via its object.
Try to call it by creating object of class DB.

```
$obj = new DB();
$obj->init();
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This method doen't have `static` keyword so you've to call it using the instance of that class and have to use this `->` operator instead of `::`

```
//this is a static method with static keyword preceding function
public static function getFacade(){
       ^^^^^^
 return new self();

}
// this is non-static method with no static keyword
public function init(){

    echo 'INIT DB';

  }
```

**Non-Static:** create an instance and then call it using `->`

```
$instance  =  new DB();
$instance->init();
```

**Static:** No need to create instance just call it using `::`

```
DB::getFacade()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `__callStatic` method only catches inaccessible or non-exist methods so if you change

```
public function init(){
    echo 'INIT DB';
  }
```

To protected it will work

```
protected function init(){
    echo 'INIT DB';
  }
```

Also I asked a question before about this and I think it might be helpful for you
[Here is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865620/make-static-out-of-non-static-magic-method)